# How to get Safari subscription (deviceToken) for web push notifications using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I can't seem to find any examples of how to do web push for Safari OSX/mac in .Net, let alone a library. There's plenty of material for *sending* a notification using the APNS, but it's really hard to understand how to get the device token in the first place. To the best of my understanding, the latest versions of Chrome/Firefox/Opera all support service workers and the Push Api on Windows, Android, and OSX. The Safari browser (on mac), on the other hand, doesn't and needs to go through APNS. iOS phones currently have zero support for web push

Comment: Please mark the answer that is helpful to you, this is respect for yourself and others. In this way, high-scoring users on the forum will be willing to help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only instructions I've found for this are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html).

Basically, you have to:

1. Register with Apple's proprietary service to get a unique ID for your service
2. Set up a ZIP and several JSON files with data describing your service and host them on your server
3. On the client-side, feature-detect and call window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission (which sends a POST request to your server with a token that you'll need later)
4. Make a POST request with the JSON of your notification to Apple's servers (even reading the documentation, I can't really tell to what URL, sorry)

So basically the same as the standard process, but completely proprietary.